# Sqlite - failed to connect database

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

**Background:**
1. Its a  c# application using Sqlite databse
2. This application creates empty db if db is not present and sync data to it from server.

**Problem:**
1. Application is getting crashed abruptly sometimes. looks like there is some unhandled exception.

2. Even I am relaunching the application its immediately getting crashed.

**Temporary Solution:**
1. Copy db to other location and delete the original db.
2. Run the application. No crash. Since no db is present, empty db is getting created by application.
3. Copy back the backup db and woo hoo Application starts fine without any crash.

**My Questions:**

1. How application is working with the same old db as It was crashing the application earlier repeatedly?

**Note:**
1. I failed to reproduce this crash in debugging as I dont know the in which scenario it is getting failed. 

2. Any input will be appreciated so dont hesitate to guess the solution.
**Prediction:**
1. Some supporting temp files are in inconsistent state and causing the problem while connecting to db and when we are creating a new database with the same name then these files are being overwritten with the fresh consistent new files.

Comment: Add some log so instead of just a crash you get a stack trace and a detailed exception.

Comment: Sorry. If you can't tell us what the exception is, no one else is going to be able to. Handle all exceptions in your application and log them to a file using Log4Net or something.

Comment: There is no log for the application and its not happening very frequently and I cant deploy new code with logs and catch statements in production

Comment: The title says "failed to connect database" but are you sure it fails to _connect_?

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are too many possible answers.
Possible issues are: - Connection refused; - Creation of database failed for unexpected reasons; - Application in an inconsistent state; and so on. As others already asked, try to add more logging in your application and add the stacktrace of exception in your question to add some details. It's not possible to help you without understanding exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Without providing any code no body can give your answer? please provide some code. Because, there are many possibilities to get this exception.

Comment: at the very least, were going to need to know the error message that is being generated when the app crashes.  Since your app is crashing with an unhandled exception, the error message will appear in the computers event log

Comment: Does your application crash, if you start it pointing to the very original db, that you copied to another location?

Comment: Sounds like a race condition to me... check whatever you are doing on database initial creation and any cleanup procedures you have, that should be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First of I want to say that I think that nobody can answer your question without any code or error.

> 1. Any input will be appreciated so dont hesitate to guess the solution.

So i'll just throw this in here:
There are many things that can make your application crash or give errors like:
 - Application is not consistent
 - Database creation goes wrong in your application
 - rights?
 - connection goes wrong before even doing anything
 - Connection goes wrong because the path is wrong
 - Connection goes wrong because your database doesn't exist
 - Syncing goes wrong

Have you tried looking at the pc's log?
Have you updated everything you are working with.
From your description I guess that somewhere in your code u make a change to your database, which makes your whole application fail.

> Note:
>   1. I failed to reproduce this crash in debugging as I dont know the in which scenario it is getting failed.

So you can get the crash when you run the application normally, but when debugging you are not able to reproduce it.
Does this happen on only your computer or does this also happen in other enviremonts

I know this is probably not the answer you're looking for but you can check all of this if u want.(if needed I will delete it)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Probably, someone is hurting database file. Maybe it's your own app if it contains several threads, or if you starting several instances simultaneously. By default SQLite is able to handle these cases, but there are configuration options that can make it not thread-safe. Take a look at [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html). Or, maybe, your application modifies the database file directly, bypassing SQLite (check the paths you're using).

Maybe SQLite fails to create write-ahead log file near the database, which results in unrecoverable database corruption if the application is killed while some transactions are active.

SQlite's database format is [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html), so you can compare valid and corrupted file and figure out what part of it is broken.

As a last resort, you can use SQLite's source code to build your own lib with debug info.